# How to run automation scripts on mobile device when USB ports on Laptop are disabled for data transfer

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

We have to perform mobile automation testing for our client, but the organization I am working for has disabled the USB port for the data transfer. We have to run the automation scripts from laptop to Mobile device without enabling the USB ports for data transfer.

Is there any workaround for this situation ? Enabling USB ports for data transfer is not possible as per the company security policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emulator in case you are running on server you could use the emulator in non gui mode . Also there are multiple cloud services which lets you test across various devices. You could you them too, eg https://bitbar.com/